# Cloud Firestore function triggers and transactions - how to return a promise correctly

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, async-await, triggers, google-cloud-functions

I have a Cloud Firestore function trigger "onCreate". Depending on the value of a given field, I would like it to either update some documents via a transaction and to copy the created document as a record in Algolia, or to execute a completely different transaction. There are therefore several conditions and I am not sure that I am returning promises correctly, as sometimes the function is not copying the record in Algolia when expected.

I paste a simplified version of the code in case someone can help.

```
exports.createArticle = functions.firestore.document('articles/{articleId}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    
  const newDocData = snap.data()

  if(newDocData) {
    const userCreatorId = newDocData.createdBy
    const userDocRef = imported.db.collection('users').doc(userCreatorId)

    if(newDocData.type === 1) {

      newDocData.objectID = newDocData.id
      indexAlgolia.saveObject(newDocData)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Article saved in Algolia with id:', newDocData.objectID )
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('ERROR while ADDING object inAlgolia:', err)
      })

      return imported.db.runTransaction(async t => {
        // do some work
        const userDoc = await t.get(userDocRef)
        const userData = userDoc.data()
        if (userData && userData.field1 > 0) {
          t.update(userDocRef, {field2: true})
        }
      }).then(result => {
        console.log('Transaction success')
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Transaction failure:', err)
      })
    } 
    else {
      const colOneRef = imported.db.collection('colOne')
      colOneRef.where('field2', '==', newDocData.field3).limit(1).get().then(snapshot => {
        return imported.db.runTransaction(async t => {
          if (snapshot.empty) {  
            t.update(userDocRef, {field3: false})
          }
          const decrement = imported.fieldValue.increment(-1)
          t.update(userDocRef, {field4: decrement})
        }).then(result => {
          console.log('Transaction success')
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log('Transaction failure:', err)
        })
      }).catch(() => 'Error while querying colOneRef')
    }
  } 
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have multiple `async/then` calls you canmake them await the result and run them as if they are synchornous but from your code I see that the second doesn't depent on the first one so you can put them in a `Promse.all()` to make the function finish faster because they will run in parallel. Your code would look like this:

```js
xports.createArticle = functions.firestore
  .document("articles/{articleId}")
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    const newDocData = snap.data();

    if (newDocData) {
      const userCreatorId = newDocData.createdBy;
      const userDocRef = imported.db.collection("users").doc(userCreatorId);

      if (newDocData.type === 1) {
        newDocData.objectID = newDocData.id;
        const firstPromise = indexAlgolia
          .saveObject(newDocData)
          .then(() => {
            console.log(
              "Article saved in Algolia with id:",
              newDocData.objectID
            );
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log("ERROR while ADDING object inAlgolia:", err);
          });

        const secondPromise = imported.db
          .runTransaction(async (t) => {
            // do some work
            const userDoc = await t.get(userDocRef);
            const userData = userDoc.data();
            if (userData && userData.field1 > 0) {
              t.update(userDocRef, { field2: true });
            }
          })
          .then((result) => {
            console.log("Transaction success");
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Transaction failure:", err);
          });

        return Promise.all([firstPromise, secondPromise]);
      } else {
        const colOneRef = imported.db.collection("colOne");
        return colOneRef
          .where("field2", "==", newDocData.field3)
          .limit(1)
          .get()
          .then((snapshot) => {
            return imported.db
              .runTransaction(async (t) => {
                if (snapshot.empty) {
                  t.update(userDocRef, { field3: false });
                }
                const decrement = imported.fieldValue.increment(-1);
                t.update(userDocRef, { field4: decrement });
              })
              .then((result) => {
                console.log("Transaction success");
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.log("Transaction failure:", err);
              });
          })
          .catch(() => "Error while querying colOneRef");
      }
     return
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you. I see that you a returning the promises associated to both the query 'colOneRef.where("field2"...' and the one associated to the transaction inside its 'then'. In this case the function will return two promises? Is that allowed?

Comment: It will return `Promise.all` and the great thing about it is that it turns those two promises in a single one. And only when all of them are done the `Promse.all` is done to. You can add into the `Promise.all` as much promises as you want. They just need to be in an Array.

Comment: Promise.all is in the body of "if", I mean in the body of "else" (else { const colOneRef = imported...), where there are two "return"

Comment: We use Promise.all only in this if `if (newDocData.type === 1) {` beacause we have there 2 promises. In the other one we don't need promise all because there is a single promise anyway. And if you don't have any promise just make a return